# High availability of scheduled agents in clustered environment

Tags: lotus-domino

One of my applications has been deemed business-critical and I'm trying to figure out a way to make my scheduled agents behave correctly in cases of failover. It doesn't need to be automatic, but an admin should be able to 'transfer' the running of the agents from one server to the other.

I was thinking of one solution of setting in a profile document the 'active' server, and have the agents (there are 4, 1 Java and 3 in LotusScript) check if they are currently running on the 'active' server, and if not, stop immediately.

Then there is IBM's workaround suggestion: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21098304 of making three agents, one 'core' agent which gets called by a 'main agent' running on the main server, and a 'failover agent' running on  the failover server, but only if the 'main server' is available.

But that solution seems a bit clunky to me, that's going to be lots of agents that need to be set up in a fiddly fashion.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My logic is similar to yours, but I don't use profile- documents (caching is a bad thing for such important task), but a central configuration document.

Agents are scheduled to run on every server.

First they read the "MasterAppServer" from the config- document. If it is another server then they try to open the database (or names.nsf, depending on what you want) on the MasterServer. If the database can be opened -> everything is ok, agent stops its work. If it cannot be opened, then the agent assumes, that the other server is down and changes the MasterAppServer- field in the config- document to his own server and runs.

Of course I write a log in the config- document whenever "MasterAppServer" changes.

That works quite well and does not need any admin intervention when one server is down.

Comment: Hi Torsten, that looks like a good solution to me. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Torsten, I've been thinking and was wondering if you had considered the case that the network fails - i.e. both servers can't reach the other server, and both locally declare themselves as 'the master'?

Comment: Nope, did not consider this case... but I don't think one could handle this scenario technically... how should I know, if the other server is not running or simply not reachable... looks both the same for the running server...

Comment: I just thought, when the network works again, if the replication conflicts are set to merge, one server will win and be the boss, so, bizarrely, replication merging would solve my issue of 'who is boss?' :-)